# Not unique table/alias: 'movie_direction'

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, alias, mysql-error-1066

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkuCl.png) 
     I am trying to fetch the movies directed by james cameron.

```
select mov_title 
from movie 
inner join movie_direction on movie.mov_id = movie_direction.dir_id
inner join movie_direction on director 
where director.fname='james' and director.lname='Cameron';
```

Comment: can you share your table schema?

Comment: why are you joining `movie_direction` table twice?

Comment: I think you wanted to join to a `director` table for your second join rather than trying to join to `movie_direction` a second time. You `on` clause looks suspect too.

Comment: movie_direction table contains movie id and director id and director table contains director id and director name and movie table contains the movies tittles

Comment: @Saima..I have updated the query in my answer check it

Comment: @RahulJain shared

Comment: @Saima Check the query i have shared. That should work for this.

Comment: I'd suggest editing the question so the second `move_direction` join is joining to `director` instead.  I'm guessing this is just a typo in the question (the main problem being the missing brackets in the joins).  The question could then be taken off hold?  Not that the OP is likely to revisit the question as they've got the answer they're after.  Ignoring any requests for clarification is just plain rude though.  Having said that - the question title does indicate the OP is trying to join to the wrong table when getting director information.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook i have edited thanks!

Comment: No, you've removed the link to the field in `director`.  What I'm trying to say is that your SQL says `inner join movie_direction on director.dir_id` on line 4, while it should say `inner join director on director.dir_id` - you're joining to the `dir_id` field in the `director` table.  Your original SQL was trying to join to the `director.dir_id` field in the `movie_direction` table which will never work - `dir_id` is qualified to the `director` table while the join is looking at the `movie_direction` table... as @RajeshPandya said in his answer.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook oky i understand thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot refer to the movie_direction table twice in the same query without giving it an alias in at least one of the joins. Give alias in one of your join or in both.

i.e.

```
inner join movie_direction md1 on {your condition}
inner join movie_direction md2 on {your condition}
```

Your query should be like this

```
SELECT 
 *
 FROM (movie INNER JOIN movie_direction ON movie.mov_id = 
 movie_direction.mov_id) INNER JOIN director ON movie_direction.dir_id = 
 director.dir_id
 WHERE    director.dir_fname='james' and director.dir_lname='Cameron';
```

Comment: It's not clear at all why they're joining to `movie_direction` twice. I suspect this is just a garbled attempt to apply multiple predicates.

Comment: @Saima..I have updated the query in my answer check it

Comment: @RajeshPandya its giving syntax error(missing operator) in join clause

Comment: @Saima, By mistake I type table name wrong, I have corrected it and double check it and working fine for me. Are you checking query in MySQL?

Comment: @RajeshPandya in ms-access

Comment: @RajeshPandya i am actualy trying to get the dir_id of james cameron  from director table then trying to get the movie ids from direction table where director id is of james then trying to fetch the movies titles of these movie ids from movie table maybe logic is wrong

Comment: @Saima, I have updated the query. Please check it. Actually, I am testing the query in MySQL now I have tested query in ms-access

Comment: thankyou so much its working now.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
    mov_title 
FROM 
    movie 
    INNER JOIN 
    movie_direction director
ON 
    movie.mov_id = director.mov_id 
WHERE 
    director.fname='james' 
AND 
    director.lname='Cameron');
```

Error in your query was you were joining mov_id with dir_id and only one join is required for this.

Comment: This'll now produce an error about `director` not being a table or alias.

Comment: My bad. Updated the query with alias.

Comment: I was more leaning towards the second join being a flub and they'd intended to join `movie_direction` to a `director` table. Of course, it would be a lot clearer if the OP had put more effort into describing their problem.

Comment: Does the above query works?

If not, please share sample data and expected result.

Comment: @RahulJain its asking to enter parameter value for director.fname

Comment: @RahulJain its working but only showing empty table not the titles of movies directed by james